# Beaming only within slurs

Tags: lilypond

I want to typeset a piece of vocal music in which beams follow the usual autobeaming rules, but *only* within notes associated to the same syllable. Notes from different syllables should not be beamed together.

To the extent possible, I would like to avoid having to manually express beams with `[]`s, because at this point in my life Lilypond knows the beaming rules better than I do. I would like to instead add some extra markup to the start and end of a syllable.

But I can't seem to find commands that let me do this. `\autoBeamOn` has some issues:

`\autoBeamOn b8 ( a8 ) \autoBeamOff g8 f8`

produces `b8 [( a8 ) g8 f8]`, not `b8[( a8)] g8 f8`. I can put a `\nobeam` command on the g8, but that doesn't work if I have two consecutive syllables: I can't see any way to get `b8[( a8)] g8([ f8])` without the explicit `[]`s. Is this possible?

Comment: It actually seems more efficient to use "["s than `\autoBeam`s — at least in terms of the number of characters typed. You mention that "LilyPond knows the beaming rules better", but to what end do you need to put LilyPond's knowledge to use, since it seems like you've overriding it anyway. Could you update your post to say more about that — or maybe post an example of where LilyPond does a better job in adhering to the rules than you do?

Comment: For what it's worth, traditional notation (i.e. before sometime in the middle of the 20th century) used beams _only_ to indicate text underlay when the note values were all 8ths or shorter and resorted to slurs only when there was at least one quarter note or longer.  If you use both slurs and beaming to indicate text underlay you run a significant risk of confusing people.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible directly, but if you dig a little bit into the auto beam engraver you’ll see that this one ends beams whenever encountering a beam, rest or breathing sign.

So you can break the auto beaming by inserting an unprinted breathing sign:

```
beamBreak =  \tweak stencil ##f \breathe

{ 
  c'16( d' e') \beamBreak f'
}
```

Using a little engraver magic we can get this done automatically whenever there is no current slur or after a slur has ended:

```
#(define (beam-break-engraver context)
   (let ((has-slur #f) (slur-ended #f) (prev-has-slur #f) (prev-slur-ended #f) (grob #f))
     (make-engraver
      (listeners
       ((slur-event engraver slur)
        ; If we find a slur event record if the slur has started or ended
        (if (< (ly:event-property slur 'span-direction) 0)
            (set! has-slur #t)
            (set! slur-ended #t))))
      ((process-music engraver)
       ; If previously there was no slur or a slur ended we create a Breathing Sign grob
       (if (or (not prev-has-slur) prev-slur-ended)
           (set! grob (ly:engraver-make-grob engraver 'BreathingSign '())))
      )
      ((stop-translation-timestep engraver)
       ; Get rid of the now unnecessary Breathing sign grob and reset properties
       (if grob (ly:grob-suicide! grob))
       (set! grob #f)
       (set! prev-has-slur has-slur)
       (if slur-ended (set! has-slur #f))
       (set! prev-slur-ended slur-ended)
       (set! slur-ended #f))
      )))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists #beam-break-engraver
  }
}

{ 
  c'16( d' e') f' g' a'( b') c''
}
```

EDIT: This method does have a little caveat. Unlike the beam engraver the auto beam engraver will not set the beamMelismaBusy property. This means that using this method will cause problems if you ever decide to add melismas without slur and manual beaming instead. To mitigate this we can add an additional engraver that simply takes care of setting this beamMelismaBusy property:

```
#(define (beam-busy-engraver context)
   (let ((beam #f))
     (make-engraver
      (listeners
       ((beam-event engraver event)
        (if (< (ly:event-property event 'span-direction) 0)
            (set! beam #t)
            (set! beam #f))))
      ((process-music engraver)
       (ly:context-set-property! context 'beamMelismaBusy beam)))))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists #beam-break-engraver
    \consists #beam-busy-engraver
  }
}

{ 
  c'16( d' e') f' g' a'( b') c''
} \addlyrics { a -- b -- c -- d -- e }

{ 
  c'16[ d' e'] f' g' a'[ b'] c''
} \addlyrics { a -- b -- c -- d -- e }
```